How to Prevent Screenshot and Screen Recording in Flutter Windows Application?
I'm developing a Flutter application for Windows and need to implement a feature to prevent users from capturing screenshots and screen recordings within the application. Despite extensive research, I haven't found any library packages or similar code to achieve this functionality.
Need to implement a feature to prevent users from capturing screenshots and screen recordings of the application.
Could someone please provide guidance or suggest a solution to achieve this in a Flutter Windows/Desktop application?
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

I remember reading this article about screenshots and video recording safety. Hope it helps to you.
